# How to replace a symbol in sed only if it occurs before a letter?

Tags: text-processing, sed, replace

In my documents, I have lots of occurences like these:

```
[["A [["b [["8 [["c [["F [["1...
```

What I need to do is to replace double brackets with single brackets, but only if there is a letter after a `[["` pattern, not a number. So that it'll look like this:

```
["A ["b [["8 ["c ["F [["1...
```

What I tried to do is this:

```
sed -i -e 's/[["[a-z A-Z]/["[a-z A-Z]/' ARD.json
```

What it does is adding a `["[a-z A-Z]` string in the beginning of every line. Also tried the same with `[[:alpha:]]` expression, does not work.

Answer (score 3):

Try:

```
$ sed -e 's/\[\[\("[[:alpha:]]\)/[\1/g' ARD.json
["A ["b [["8 ["c ["F [["1
```

With GNU sed:

```
sed -re 's/\[\[("[[:alpha:]])/[\1/g'
```

Comment: I'd move the `\(` to include the `[` so that the replacement pattern consists of just `\1`